# How do I determine if one value is almost like another value (e.g. street abbreviations)?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question about some elements in a DataRow. I have an array of DataRow elments like so:

```
 DataRow[] rows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToArray();
```

I am using a loop to loop through the elements like so:

```
        for ( int i = 0; i < rows.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (rows[i].ItemArray.ElementAt(0).ToString().Equals("ORDER"))
            {
                 ...do stuff...
            }
        }
```

In the "do stuff" section I need to check an address to see if it is the same as a previous order by the person. So the address can change, be the same, or be similiar.

By similiar I mean something like this:

```
11555 Old Oregon Tr
11555 Old Oregon Trail
11555 Old Oregon Trl.
```

All three are the same address, just variations. Now, my question. Is there a way to run a like operation on an element of a DataRow array? I want to check if the address is like the other from a previous order. I've been looking around a little and haven't really found any proof that you can but I wanted to ask the question to see if anyone knew of a solution, or workaround per say.

Comment: I think this could more effectively be done at the database level, is this a Microsoft SQL database?

Comment: It is a ms sql database, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may get dinged for this because it doesn't **technically** answer your question directly, but consider this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/529242/4/0). It leverages `SOUNDEX` to perform this operation. A query might look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Addresses
WHERE SOUNDEX(Address) = SOUNDEX('11555 Old Oregon Tr')
```

so as you're looping through the rows you could do something like this:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Addresses WHERE SOUNDEX(Address) = SOUNDEX(@Address)";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    // perform your logic in here because now you're looping through the realted
    // rows and the row you queried against
}
```

where `conn` is a `SqlConnection` object.

Comment: Would this work if my query was '11555 Oold Oregon Trail'? Since you it would actually speak the whole word trail, would it get hits against 'tr and 'trl.'?

Comment: @Brett, yes it would, have a look at the Fiddle, it proves that. All three queries return the very same result, all three records, because all three sound the same mathmatically.

Comment: @Brett, no worries, I'm glad I could be of assistance!